# Can we define more than one <leader> key in Vimrc?

Tags: vim, vi

If we want to assign more shortcuts mapped in our vimrc file then what are the options we have ?
Can we multiple leader keys ?

Comment: For a completely disparate take on [not] using *<Leader>* for key mappings, you should go check out Tim Pope's opinion [http://vimcasts.org/blog/2014/02/follow-my-leader/](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2014/02/follow-my-leader/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Changing mapleader

As the value of `mapleader` is used at the moment the mapping is defined, you can indeed change that while plugins are loading. For that, you have to explicitly `:runtime` the plugins in your `~/.vimrc` (and count on the canonical *include guard* to prevent redefinition later):

```
let mapleader = ','
runtime! plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
runtime! ...
let mapleader = '\'
runime! plugin/mark.vim
...
```

#### Individual mapping configuration

However, as most plugins allow customization of mappings via `<Plug>...` mappings (or alternatively something like `g:{pluginname}_mapleader` variables), this coarse segregation shouldn't be necessary. You can individually configure the mappings *before* the plugin is sourced (i.e. in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
nmap ,cc <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
xmap ,cc <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
nmap <Leader>m <Plug>MarkSet
```

### Suitable keys

As most keys are taken, there aren't many alternatives. I guess the most common prefixes are:

- <kbd>\</kbd>
- <kbd>,</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>

Note that with the individual mapping configuration, one prefix key is enough; just add additional keys to disambiguate. Of course, this means that all (now two-, or even three-key) will be longer to invoke. I usually reserve the first key after `<Leader>` for a namespace (e.g. `<Leader>c...` for commenting, `<Leader>s...` for substitutions), but that's pure personal preference.

Comment: Is it possible to map two mapleaders at the same time, so if I press `\<Space>` or `,` it'll execute mappings?

Comment: @hhsnopek: You can define an alias for your leader, e.g. `:map , <Leader>`. Then, both `<Leader>x` and `,x` will work.

Comment: Just as a warning, if you're looking not to break compatibility with other Vim users: `,` is `;` (repeat last `f/F/t/T` command) in the reverse direction and some people like me, may make heavy use of it. (A typical use pattern would be `F"` to find the next quote, `;` a few times to keep jumping forward to the next quote yet, and then the thought, "oops, went too far" is followed by `,`.